# Google Oauth error: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using Google's Oauth 2.0 to upload videos to Youtube via our server.
My client ID is a "service account". I downloaded the json key and added it to my solution.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 private async Task Run(string filePath)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            var keyUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/content/oauth_key.json");
            using (var stream = new FileStream(keyUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });
```

When I run it, I get this error: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set.

However, in my json there is no "client secret":

```
{
  "private_key_id": "9d98c06b3e730070806dcf8227578efd0ba9989b",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICdQIBADANBgkqhk etc,
  "client_email": "546239405652-8igo05a5m8cutggehk3rk3hspjfm3t04@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "546239405652-8igo05a5m8cutggehk3rk3hspjfm3t04.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

so I assume I overlooked something.
Maybe I can't use the "service account" ? don't know...

Comment: did  you tried ? any solution ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an expert on C# but it looks like you were trying to use the service account to do the OAuth2 web server flow, which shouldn't work.
You probably want to use [ServiceAccountCredential](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0/documentation/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1ServiceAccountCredential.html) instead.
For more information about different Google OAuth2 flows, please refer to the doc for [web server](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer), [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount), etc.

Comment: 404.  This is how not to answer an SO question

Comment: `Service accounts will only work with Gsuite email accounts. The admin of the Gsuite (domain) account will have to grant the service account access to the users email account. Unfortunately i don't have access to a Gsuite account so cant help you set it up. This might help Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority

If this is a normal Gmail user account you are trying to access then you cant use a service account. You will either have to go though the SMTP / IMAP servers or using Oauth2 to authenticate the user.`

Answer (score 28):

The solution that uses `json` file is quite similar.

Here is sample that create `VisionService` using `GoogleCredential` object created from `json` file with `ServiceAccountCredential`.

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
        .CreateScoped(VisionService.Scope.CloudPlatform);
}

var service = new VisionService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "my-app-name",
});
```

this sample require two `NuGet` packages:

```
Google.Apis.Vision.v1  
Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2
```

Comment: The main focus here shoud be _GoogleCredential.FromStream_ following by _CreateScoped_

Answer (score 9):

I managed to get a service account to work with a P12 file, But would like to know how to use with the JSON file, Or just value from the JSON file to create the certificate.

To get the token

```
    private static String GetOAuthCredentialViaP12Key()
    {
        const string serviceAccountEmail = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL;
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var scope = DriveService.Scope.Drive + " https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds";
        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential( new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                                                       {
                                                            Scopes  = new[] { scope }
                                                       }.FromCertificate(certificate) );

        if (credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result == false)
        {

            return null;
        }

        return credential.Token.AccessToken;
    }
```

And this is how I used the token I got

```
        // Initialize the variables needed to make the request
        OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters {AccessToken = token};
        GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1", parameters);
        SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
        service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
```

Comment: What is **DriveService.Scope.Drive** ? namespace, references ?

Comment: I too was looking for a way to implement with the JSON file. The SDK version 1.9.3 and later support this.

See: [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/GoogleCredential.cs#L96)

Here's a quick sample of how to use it:

    var stream = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
    credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly });